# Click on ASP.net Gridview's Header causing post back. How to stop this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using ASP.net to build a website. In there there is a gridview.
Problem is when I click on the gridview's header it causes to post back of the page. Dont know how to stop this. Here is the code

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gridEmployee" Width="100%" RowStyle-Height="15" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2"
                HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" RowStyle-BackColor="Black" RowStyle-ForeColor="#3A3A3A"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="1px" OnRowCreated="gridEmployee_RowCreated" OnSelectedIndexChanging="gridEmployee_SelectedIndexChanging"
                ClientIDMode="Static" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="employee_master_id_pk"
                AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnPageIndexChanging="gridEmployee_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#string.Format("/images/profile_full/{0}",Eval("image_url")) %>' Width="50px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NAME" ReadOnly="true" DataField="call_name">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="70%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MOBILE" ReadOnly="true" DataField="mobile_no">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="30%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
                </Columns>
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#0AA6FF" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="true" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#199e38" ForeColor="White" Height="20px" Font-Size="Medium"></HeaderStyle>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#f6f7f9" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Below is the error message that showing

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument. 
>   Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.    at
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
>   String argument)    at System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String
>   uniqueID, String eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   ASP.private_task_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\Users\testl\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\cc51fe2f\b39cd5d2\App_Web_wtae1pov.4.cs:line 0    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

The question is about sorting or not.

If you want the GridView no to be sortable you have to set

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridEmployee"  AllowSorting="false"
```

if you want to allow sorting but without a full postback you have to add a UpdatePanel around the GridView

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:GridView ID="gridEmployee"
```

Comment: define "not working" your hearder are still clickable?